# Crash ERROR_CGDataProvider_BufferIsNotReadable + 16 only for iOS >= 11.3

Tags: ios, crash, core-graphics

My application works with filters and image transformations. In the new versions of iOS, starting from 11.3, I periodically see the crashes. I can't repeat them. Can anyone already encounter such crashes? All the algorithms work in the main thread.

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, having the same issue, not able to reproduce since a few months now